# How to remove a script that was queued up in the footer in a parent theme

Tags: child-theme

I have a parent theme that does this:

```
function parent_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('parent-scripts', '/uri/to/script', array('jquery'), VERSION);
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'parent_enqueue_scripts');
```

So I created this function in my child theme

```
function child_reset_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('parent-scripts');
    wp_deregister_script('parent-scripts');
}
```

But my attempts to use it have not succeeded, and `parent-scripts` keeps getting loaded. I have tried the following:

1. Removing the parent callback from wp_footer
2. Adding `child_reset_scripts()` to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `wp_print_scripts`, and `wp_footer`
3. Setting the priority to 20 for all callbacks (parent theme does not set priorities so the default is 10)

What I assume is that in all these attempts, `child_reset_scripts()` is still getting called BEFORE the parent's callback to `wp_footer`, but I don't know how to change this order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `after_setup_theme` to remove the parent handler, which runs once both the parent & child functions have been loaded:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function () {
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'parent_enqueue_scripts' );
});
```